# How to use 'OR' condition in sphinxsearch

Tags: search, full-text-search, sphinx

I tried to use `SELECT * FROM test WHERE status=1 OR attribute=123`

but I got error `ERROR 1064 (42000): sphinxql: syntax error, unexpected OR, expecting $end near`

Then, i tried to change to `select *, if(attribute=123 or status=1, 1, 0) as filter from test where filter=1` but it's still not working in sphinx_2.2.11 or sphinx_3.0.3. What should i do to achieve this feature?

the schema looks like:

`sql_attr_uint = status
 sql_attr_multi = attribute`

Answer (score 0):

This is not supported in Sphinx yet (up to 3.0.3).

Manticore Search (fork of Sphinx) supports it since version 2.4.1